# Process a SSAS via Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-analysis-services

We have a requirement wherein we need to process SSAS via ADF as the ETL operations is being done via ADF into an Azure SQL database

any help regarding this will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a linked server across a On Prem database instance and Analysis service instance and then execute TSQL on the database instance via ADF to process the cube.
You can refer the below Doc :
https://github.com/furmangg/automating-azure-analysis-services/blob/master/LinkedServer/SQL%20Linked%20Server%20to%20Azure%20Analysis%20Services.sql